# Public Insights

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-insights

With the new ability for anyone to see certain insights from pages without admin permissions, I was curious if this extends to the graph api, specifically in regards to the graph of fan growth. If you hover your mouse over a data point, it'll tell you the new fans / 7 days of that particular point in time -- is there any way to query this automatically with either fql or the regular graph api?

I've tried `SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id = 224383614973 AND metric = 'page_fan_adds' AND end_time=1342915199 AND period=86400` to query the McDonald's Canada new fans for a one-day period, but it requires a valid access_token.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for the late reply but it might help someone. You can use the graph explorer to build your FQL query:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=CocaColaCanada%2Finsights

Also all the metrics for the `page` start with `page_` and are available here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/#page_stories

Some of them are not public.
**In all cases** you need valid `access_token`

**UPDATE:**

I've run a script for macdonald using the 233 metrics that facebook offers to see which one are public metrics for a page. Here is the result:

## McDonalds(233 metrics)

- application_active_users: no
- application_active_users_locale: no
- application_active_users_city: no
- application_active_users_country: no
- application_active_users_gender: no
- application_active_users_age: no
- application_active_users_gender_age: no
- application_installed_users: no
- application_installed_users_locale: no
- application_installed_users_city: no
- application_installed_users_country: no
- application_installed_users_gender: no
- application_installed_users_age: no
- application_installed_users_gender_age: no
- application_installation_adds: no
- application_installation_adds_unique: no
- application_installation_removes: no
- application_installation_removes_unique: no
- application_tos_views: no
- application_tos_views_unique: no
- application_permission_views_top: no
- application_permission_views_top_unique: no
- application_permission_grants_top: no
- application_permission_grants_top_unique: no
- application_block_adds: no
- application_block_adds_unique: no
- application_block_removes: no
- application_block_removes_unique: no
- application_mobile_app_installs: no
- application_like_adds: no
- application_like_adds_unique: no
- application_like_removes: no
- application_like_removes_unique: no
- application_comment_adds: no
- application_comment_adds_unique: no
- application_photos: no
- application_photos_unique: no
- application_shares: no
- application_shares_unique: no
- application_status_updates: no
- application_status_updates_unique: no
- application_stream_stories: no
- application_stream_stories_unique: no
- application_feed_form_views: no
- application_feed_form_views_unique: no
- application_feed_form_views_login: no
- application_feed_form_views_login_unique: no
- application_feed_form_views_logout: no
- application_widget_activity_views: no
- application_widget_activity_views_unique: no
- application_widget_activity_views_login: no
- application_widget_activity_views_login_unique: no
- application_widget_activity_views_logout: no
- application_widget_activity_views_external_referrals: no
- application_widget_comments_views: no
- application_widget_comments_views_unique: no
- application_widget_comments_views_login: no
- application_widget_comments_views_login_unique: no
- application_widget_comments_views_logout: no
- application_widget_fan_views: no
- application_widget_fan_views_unique: no
- application_widget_fan_views_login: no
- application_widget_fan_views_login_unique: no
- application_widget_fan_views_logout: no
- application_widget_fan_views_external_referrals: no
- application_widget_like_views: no
- application_widget_like_views_unique: no
- application_widget_like_views_login: no
- application_widget_like_views_login_unique: no
- application_widget_like_views_logout: no
- application_widget_like_views_external_referrals: no
- application_widget_live_stream_views: no
- application_widget_live_stream_views_unique: no
- application_widget_live_stream_views_login: no
- application_widget_live_stream_views_login_unique: no
- application_widget_live_stream_views_logout: no
- application_widget_live_stream_views_external_referrals: no
- application_widget_recommendation_views: no
- application_widget_recommendation_views_unique: no
- application_widget_recommendation_views_login: no
- application_widget_recommendation_views_login_unique: no
- application_widget_recommendation_views_logout: no
- application_widget_recommendation_views_external_referrals: no
- application_widget_share_views: no
- application_widget_share_views_unique: no
- application_widget_views: no
- application_widget_views_unique: no
- application_widget_views_login: no
- application_widget_views_login_unique: no
- application_widget_views_logout: no
- application_opengraph_action_create: no
- application_opengraph_action_delete: no
- application_opengraph_object_create: no
- application_opengraph_object_update: no
- application_opengraph_story_impressions: no
- application_opengraph_story_click: no
- application_opengraph_story_like: no
- application_opengraph_story_unlike: no
- application_opengraph_story_comment: no
- application_opengraph_story_hide: no
- application_opengraph_story_hide_all: no
- application_opengraph_story_report_spam: no
- application_opengraph_link_impression: no
- application_opengraph_link_click: no
- application_opengraph_timeline_impressions: no
- application_opengraph_timeline_spam: no
- application_opengraph_timeline_clicked: no
- application_canvas_views: no
- application_canvas_views_unique: no
- application_canvas_views_login: no
- application_canvas_views_login_unique: no
- application_canvas_views_logout: no
- application_canvas_views_internal_referrals: no
- application_canvas_views_external_referrals: no
- application_tab_views: no
- application_tab_views_unique: no
- application_api_calls: no
- application_api_calls_top: no
- application_api_calls_unique: no
- application_api_errors: no
- application_api_errors_rate: no
- application_api_errors_top: no
- application_api_time_average: no
- application_canvas_errors: no
- application_canvas_errors_rate: no
- application_canvas_time_average: no
- page_fans_locale: no
- page_fans_city: no
- page_fans_country: **ok**
- page_fans_gender_age: no
- page_fan_adds: no
- page_fan_adds_unique: no
- page_fans_by_like_source: no
- page_fans_by_like_source_unique: no
- page_fan_removes: no
- page_fan_removes_unique: no
- page_friends_of_fans: no
- page_tab_views_login_top_unique: no
- page_tab_views_login_top: no
- page_views: no
- page_views_unique: no
- page_views_login: no
- page_views_login_unique: no
- page_views_logout: no
- page_views_external_referrals: no
- page_posts_impressions: no
- page_posts_impressions_unique: no
- page_posts_impressions_paid: no
- page_posts_impressions_paid_unique: no
- page_posts_impressions_organic: no
- page_posts_impressions_organic_unique: no
- page_posts_impressions_viral: no
- page_posts_impressions_viral_unique: no
- page_posts_impressions_frequency_distribution: no
- post_stories: no
- post_storytellers: no
- post_stories_by_action_type: no
- post_storytellers_by_action_type: no
- post_impressions: no
- post_impressions_unique: no
- post_impressions_paid: no
- post_impressions_paid_unique: no
- post_impressions_fan: no
- post_impressions_fan_unique: no
- post_impressions_fan_paid: no
- post_impressions_fan_paid_unique: no
- post_impressions_organic: no
- post_impressions_organic_unique: no
- post_impressions_viral: no
- post_impressions_viral_unique: no
- post_impressions_by_story_type: no
- post_impressions_by_story_type_unique: no
- post_consumptions: no
- post_consumptions_unique: no
- post_consumptions_by_type: no
- post_consumptions_by_type_unique: no
- post_engaged_users: no
- post_negative_feedback: no
- post_negative_feedback_unique: no
- post_negative_feedback_by_type: no
- post_negative_feedback_by_type_unique: no
- domain_feed_clicks: no
- domain_feed_views: no
- domain_stories: no
- domain_widget_comments_adds: no
- domain_widget_comments_views: no
- domain_widget_comments_feed_views: no
- domain_widget_comments_feed_clicks: no
- domain_widget_like_views: no
- domain_widget_likes: no
- domain_widget_like_feed_views: no
- domain_widget_like_feed_clicks: no
- domain_widget_send_views: no
- domain_widget_send_clicks: no
- domain_widget_send_inbox_views: no
- domain_widget_send_inbox_clicks: no
- page_stories: no
- page_storytellers: no
- page_stories_by_story_type: no
- page_storytellers_by_story_type: no
- page_storytellers_by_age_gender: no
- page_storytellers_by_country: **ok**
- page_storytellers_by_locale: no
- page_impressions: no
- page_impressions_unique: no
- page_impressions_paid: no
- page_impressions_paid_unique: no
- page_impressions_organic: no
- page_impressions_organic_unique: no
- page_impressions_viral: no
- page_impressions_viral_unique: no
- page_impressions_by_story_type: no
- page_impressions_by_story_type_unique: no
- page_impressions_by_city_unique: no
- page_impressions_by_age_gender_unique: no
- page_impressions_frequency_distribution: no
- page_impressions_viral_frequency_distribution: no
- page_engaged_users: no
- page_consumptions: no
- page_consumptions_unique: no
- page_consumptions_by_consumption_type: no
- page_consumptions_by_consumption_type_unique: no
- page_places_checkin_total: no
- page_places_checkin_total_unique: no
- page_places_checkin_mobile: no
- page_places_checkin_mobile_unique: no
- page_places_checkins_by_age_gender: no
- page_places_checkins_by_locale: no
- page_places_checkins_by_country: no
- page_negative_feedback: no
- page_negative_feedback_unique: no
- page_negative_feedback_by_type: no
- page_negative_feedback_by_type_unique: no

Started at: 2013-04-17 02:14:29
Ended at: 2013-04-17 02:17:13
Second elapsed: 164s

Comment: In the latest versions FQL is no longer supported. Graph API is recommended.

Comment: All that list and only 2 are available publicly! thats harsh